# Void* struct just getting address through socket how can I solve this

Tags: c, sockets, struct

Im very new to C programing, but i need to accomplish some task using sockets

I have a Struct with an element being void*, this struct will be transmitted trough Socket,

```
     typedef struct TXData {
            unsigned short code;
            int DataSize;
            void *Data;
        } TXData ;
    TXData  data_send;

int value=50;
data_send.Data=&value;
```

how can i actually pass integer in value to data_send?, or will it automatically get it while sending thorough socket?

My intention of keeping void*data is to transmit any type of data, whether it may be int, double, char

and I'm sending data to socket in this way. data length will be calculated before hand and updated in struct before sending.

```
datalen=data_send.DataSize;

        if (sendto(sd, &data_send, datalen, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&groupSock,sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
        {
            perror("sending datagram message");
        }
```

but at the receive pc im re casting data accordingly but i  just getting addresses for data which is actually reference to the sending PC, can any one help me ?

Comment: so how can  i send the actual data?, my intention is to send the iniger value to the next system

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the actual data, not only the pointer. One possible solution is to *serialize* the structure, and send each member one by one, followed by the actual data.

Something similar to the following (***pseudo***) code:

```
uint16_t code = (uint16_t) htons(data_send.code);
int32_t size = (int32_t) htonl(data_send.DataSize);
void *data = data_send.Data;

send(&code, sizeof code);
send(&size, sizeof data);
send(data, data_send.DataSize);
```

On the receiving end you basically do the opposite of what the sender is doing, receiving each member one by one and convert it back into the structure:

```
uint16_t code;
int32_t size;

recv(&code, sizeof code);
recv(&size, sizeof size);

data_recv.code = ntohs(code);
data_recv.DataSize = ntohl(size);

data_recv.Data = malloc(data_recv.DataSize);
recv(data_recv.Data, data_recv.DataSize);
```

Comment: but this library is for windows i guess.. I'm working on a Linux system To be precise Linux modified for National Instruments

Comment: @ninu The code shown is *pseduo* code, not real code. It only shows the principle. But the principle is platform-independent. As is the use of the actual and real types `uint16_t` and `int32_t` as well as the `htons` and `ntohs` etc. functions. The only thing you have to modify is `send` to the real `sendto` call you use, and then it should work on either platform.

Comment: yes i understood the principle and im trying to implement in my system, i have found the same library working for linux

Comment: it worked !! so we also need to add an element in struct to reverse cast the type of data

Answer (score 0):

> My intention ... is to transmit any type of data, whether it may be int, double, char

There are several problems that you need to be aware of. From your question it seems that you are already aware that it makes no sense to transmit pointer values. But there is more to it than that.

Directly transmitting a normal  struct is a no-go. Different computers may have different encodings of the same C struct due to different padding rules. If you want to use structs, you need to use packed structs.

Another problem is "type size". The ordinary types like `int`, `float`, etc. may have different size on different computers. When you transfer data you need to be specific about sizes.

Yet another problem is endianess. Some computers have LSB first and other computers have MSB first. When you transfer data you need a machine independent format.

And finally... you also need a mechanism that allows the receiver to know what type of data it is receiving, i.e. is it a 32 bit signed integer, is it a 64 bit floating point value and so on.

So to cover all this you need to define a protocol for the data exchange, i.e. a transfer protocol describing all formats and rules.

That can be done in many different ways. A simple example:

```
Byte 0 : Type
Byte 1..N : Data

where

Type equal 0 means: Data is a 32 bit integer with MSB first
Type equal 1 means: Data is a 62 bit floating point value with MSB first
Type equal 2 means: ...
and so on
```

For transfer of e.g. text strings or binary blobs you'll also need a way to transmit a length field.

Once you have the transfer protocol in place, you need to write an encoder and a decoder.

So your system is:

```
Data on PC1 in PC1s format
         |
         |--> Encoder --> Data in transfer protocol format in PC1
                                      |
                                      |--> Socket transmit
                                                |
                                                |
                                      |<-- Socket receive
                                      |
         |<-- Decoder <-- Data in transfer protocol format in PC2
         |
Data on PC2 in PC2s format
```

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct TXData 
{
    unsigned short code;
    size_t DataSize;
    unsigned char Data[];
} TXData ;



TXData *alloc(size_t size)
{
    TXData  *data_send = malloc(sizeof(*data_send) + size);

    /* some error checks */
    data_send -> DataSize = size;

    return data_send;
}



//and then:


if (sendto(sd, data_send, data_send -> DataSize + sizeof(*data_send), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&groupSock,sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
/* ....*/
```